# PowerQuery - Master & Sub Rows - Reference Values of Another Row Based on Formula or Logic

Tags: excel, powerquery

PowerQuery - Master & Sub Rows - Reference Values of Another Row Based on Formula or Logic

I am analyzing vulnerability scanner export data in Excel and developing ticketing from it using some power queries. I've gotten the data into a format that allows me to analyze and determine which have tickets already and which do not. For those that do not, they may already have a master ticket created, but some may not. During my analysis, I will determine if a ticket needs to be created or not, and the output from that should include the master ticket number (if one already created) to link it to, or if no master ticket has already been created, then use the index number of the master ticket that will also be created.

Some example data of what I'm starting out with is:

| CVE | Description | Team | Locations | Master | Matching Ticket | Create Ticket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-2021-12345 | Vuln Description 1 |  |  | True | Tic-1234 | No |
| CVE-2021-12345 | Vuln Description 1 | Ops | 1, 2, 3 |  |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-12345 | Vuln Description 1 | Dev | 4, 5, 6 |  |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-12345 | Vuln Description 1 | InfoSec | 7, 8, 9 |  |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-67891 | Vuln Description 2 |  |  | True |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-67891 | Vuln Description 2 | Dev | 4, 5, 6 |  |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-23456 | Vuln Description 3 |  |  | True | Tic-4567 | No |
| CVE-2021-23456 | Vuln Description 3 | InfoSec | 7, 8, 9 |  |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-23456 | Vuln Description 3 | Ops | 1, 2, 3 |  |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-78912 | Vuln Description 4 |  |  | True |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-78912 | Vuln Description 4 | Dev | 4, 5, 6 |  |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-78912 | Vuln Description 4 | Ops | 4, 5, 6 |  |  | Yes |
| CVE-2021-78912 | Vuln Description 4 | InfoSec | 4, 5, 6 |  |  | Yes |

I can understand the logic of getting the matching this as I want it with an excel formula as something like: `If create ticket equals yes, then (if master does not equal true, then (if the lookup for the matching CVE that has master equals true and has a value in matching ticket, then return the value in matching ticket column, else (if master does not equal true, then (if the lookup for the matching CVE that has master equals true, and does not have a value in matching ticket, then result the value of an index number, else leave blank), else leave blank), else leave blank), else leave blank).`

However, I'm trying to make this more repeatable with a power query and I'm having trouble finding the right functions. From this existing dataset, I would use Power Query to create a new query/table and filter all of the rows that do not have yes in the create ticket column, and add an index row. From there I'd like to add a new column specifically for this linking logic, and I can't seem to get the logic right. I know that I can use if then logic in those columns, but getting the data from another row based on matching values is what I am having trouble with.

The output I'm essentially looking for is:

| CVE | Description | Team | Locations | Master | Create Ticket | Index | Linked Ticket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-2021-12345 | Vuln Description 1 | Ops | 1, 2, 3 |  | Yes | 1 | Tic-1234 |
| CVE-2021-12345 | Vuln Description 1 | Dev | 4, 5, 6 |  | Yes | 2 | Tic-1234 |
| CVE-2021-12345 | Vuln Description 1 | InfoSec | 7, 8, 9 |  | Yes | 3 | Tic-1234 |
| CVE-2021-67891 | Vuln Description 2 |  |  | True | Yes | 4 |  |
| CVE-2021-67891 | Vuln Description 2 | Dev | 4, 5, 6 |  | Yes | 5 | 4 |
| CVE-2021-23456 | Vuln Description 3 | InfoSec | 7, 8, 9 |  | Yes | 6 | Tic-4567 |
| CVE-2021-23456 | Vuln Description 3 | Ops | 1, 2, 3 |  | Yes | 7 | Tic-4567 |
| CVE-2021-78912 | Vuln Description 4 |  |  | True | Yes | 8 |  |
| CVE-2021-78912 | Vuln Description 4 | Dev | 4, 5, 6 |  | Yes | 9 | 8 |
| CVE-2021-78912 | Vuln Description 4 | Ops | 4, 5, 6 |  | Yes | 10 | 8 |
| CVE-2021-78912 | Vuln Description 4 | InfoSec | 4, 5, 6 |  | Yes | 11 | 8 |

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Please explain why Vuln4 Ops and InfoSec both repeat twice in the output, but Vuln2 Dev only appears once in output.   Also why is Yes in the index column in the last two output rows

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed it. That was an error in the table contents. Took me about 30 minutes to be able to post because stack overflow kept giving an error that there was code, but there was not. The mistakenly added rows may have ended up in some copy/paste things I was doing to try and fix the problem to allow me to post.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically just filtering and merging

Filter Master = True, merge that against the original table and expand matching ticket

Filter for create ticket = yes

Add index

Filter Master = True, merge that against the data before this step and expand index

do an if/then statement to determine null, ticket or index

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"CVE"},Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Master] = true)),{"CVE"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Matching Ticket"}, {"zLinked Ticket"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Table2", each ([Create Ticket] = "Yes")),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 1, 1),
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index",{"CVE"},Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each ([Master] = true)),{"CVE"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Table2", {"Index"}, {"Index.1"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table1", "Custom", each if [Master]=null and [zLinked Ticket]=null then [Index.1] else if [Master]=null then [zLinked Ticket] else null),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"zLinked Ticket", "Index.1"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: did that work for you?